# Mat-table changes observable

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

Let's say I have mat-table in html

```
 <div>
     <table mat-table [dataSource]="mydataDataSource" #myDataSortReference="matSort" matSort multiTemplateDataRows matSortDisableClear>
     <somerows mat-sort-header> </tr></th>
</table>
```

and in .ts file

```
  @ViewChildren('mydataSortReference', { read: MatSort }) myDataSortReference: QueryList<MatSort>;
```

and

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.myDataSortReference.changes.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe(() => {
    this.sortMyDataMySpecialFunction();
  });
}
```

Why the changes are emitted after page refresh, but not on first load of the page? What triggers changes of this component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give "mydataDataSource" an updated value, say something like:

```
  sortMyDataMySpecialFunction(): void {
     mydataDataSource = UPDATED_TABLE_DATA;
  });
```

Assuming that sortMyDataMySpecialFunction() does data retrieval before sorting, otherwise as soon as you get your data (from server/etc.) assign it, preferably in the "ngAfterViewInit" function

Edit:
The sortData function gets called on certain occasions:

> Called after changes are made to the filtered data or when sort
> changes are emitted from MatSort.

according to the Angular [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource)